# sort each column(field) in a file separately

Tags: sort

I am aware that it is possible to `sort` primarily by one field and secondarily by another field. For example:

```
$ echo -e "1 5\n1 4\n8 2\n1 9" | sort -k 1,1n -k 2,2n
1 4
1 5
1 9
8 2
$
```

However, am I correct that `sort` always keeps the lines intact, e.g. it is not possible to sort in a way that output would be following:

```
1 2
1 4
1 5
8 9
```

If this is not possible with `sort`, then what would be the correct tool for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tom Zych](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6079/tom-zych) noted

```
paste -d ' ' <(echo -e "1 5\n1 4\n8 2\n1 9" |
               cut -f1 -d' ' |
               sort -n
           ) <(echo -e "1 5\n1 4\n8 2\n1 9" |
               cut -f2 -d' ' |
               sort -n
           )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing that, I’d first split up the lines into fields, each
field going into its own file; could use `cut` or `awk` or various other
tools for that. Then `sort` each file separately. Then `paste` them back
together.